# Wait for a thread/asynctask to complete in a method so that it can be the returned value of the method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Hello Stack Overflowers,

I am working on an android application and am making a todo list application. One of the requirements is to check on a webserver if a device has already registered on the server.
From what I understand it has to be done in a background thread to avoid UI Thread lockups.

I have a method that will then check as follows:

```
    public String isRegisteredOnServer {
    // Check here on server
    return resultOfServerCheck;
    }
```

How can I implement it, or are there alternatives approaches to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should learn about [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `AsyncTask`

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String str) {
    // Do all the time consuming code here
    return result; //Return your string from here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    setResultValue(result);
    }

}.execute();

private void setResultValue(String value) {
// You get your string here
}
```

Comment: I have an if statement in the UI Thread onCreate function that relies on the result of the Asynctask, That's why I have to wait for the completion of the Asynctask. But right now that is not the case.

Comment: @RoëlGonzalez Well in that case you need to think of a different approach because `Asynctask` will spawn a new `Thread` and your `onCreate()` code will be executed without waiting for your AsyncTask's response. However you can update the UI after AsyncTask completes if that's what you want.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it again

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK provides such a functionality. You can look into `AsyncTask`.

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).